# Deleting singleton object and reconstructing in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton

I've this situation wherein a singleton class creates object of a model and is used further in my code.

Now, the problem is that occasionally the connection between application and database is broken and all subsequent calls to the singleton fail. While I'm working on fixing the issue, a workaround is required immediately. I believe the solution I'm thinking of, would work but not sure if it will leak memory, cause deadlocks etc.

Here's the original (partial) code:

```
1    file_path = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
2    require file_path + '/action_factory'
3    require 'erb'
4    
5    class Manager
6    
7                    def initialize(logger)
8                            @logger = logger
9                    end
10    
11                    def log_exception(e,method_name)
12                            @logger.log :ERROR,"Manager",method_name,'',$$,'',e.backtrace[0] + ": Uncaught Exception " + e.message,DateTime.now,'system',''
13                            e.backtrace.shift
14                            @logger.log :ERROR,"Manager",method_name,'',$$,''," from " + e.backtrace.join("\n from ") + "(" + e.class.to_s + ")",DateTime.now,'system',''
15                    end

16                    def execute_action
17                            return false if addresses.collect{|a| a if !a.to_s.empty?}.compact.empty?
18                            begin
19                                    action = ActionFactory.instance().get_action(type)
20                                    return true
21                            rescue Exception => e
22                                    action = nil ####### I'm planning to add this line ####
23                                    log_exception(e,this_method_name)
24                                    return false
25                            end
26                    end
27    end



28    require 'singleton'
29    $file_path=File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))
30    Dir[$file_path + '/actions/*_action.rb'].each { |filename| require filename }
31    
32    class ActionFactory
33            include Singleton
34    
35            def get_action(type)
36                    action_type_obj = ActionType.find(:first, :select => "action_name", :conditions => ["id=?",type])

37                    if(action_type_obj.nil? or action_type_obj.action_name.nil?)
38                            raise "Undefined Action Type"
39                    else
40                            return eval("Actions::#{action_type_obj.action_name}").instance
41                    end
42            end

43    end
```

The problem is that oracle connection is disconnected sometimes and the statement #36 fails returning InvalidStatement exception. All subsequent calls of the statement 19 fail.

I'm planning to add a statement : action = nil in the exception block in line 22. Will that suffice as a workaround or would it bring more issues like memory leakages, deadlocks etc?

If there is a better solution, I'll be glad to hear.

Thanks

Comment: I just added an attribute my_data and method set_my_data to the ActionFactory class and tried the following on console:    `  ac_factory = ActionFactory.instance  
=> #<ActionFactory:0x2b0a9b40d280>  
>> ac_factory.set_my_data "hello"  
=> "hello"  
>> ac_factory = nil  
=> nil  
>> ac_factory = ActionFactory.instance  
=> #<ActionFactory:0x2b0a9b40d280 @my_data="hello">`

Comment: Seems that the same object is returned.